# mysql procedure call in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Any simple example of mysql stored procedure and example to show how to call that procedure from codeigniter php.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

a stored procedure for insert operation:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `database_name`.`procedure_name`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `procedure_name`( IN id INT,valueTEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE queryString VARCHAR(100);

SET @id= id;
SET @value= LOWER(value);

SET @queryString = CONCAT("INSERT INTO table_name( field_id, field_value ) VALUES ( ",@id,"'",@value,"'");

PREPARE stmt FROM @queryString;

EXECUTE stmt;



END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This simple stored procedure lets you insert **id** and **value** in
 **table_name**

```
$Query= $this->db->query("CALL procedure_name($ID,'$name')");
```

Now easily call the procedure as a normal query